# MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands in dynamically created MetroWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

How to bind/create MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands in dynamically created MetroWindow through Caliburn.Micro IWindowManager Show method?

For example, I've created a custom IWindowManager implementation to always create MetroWindow instead of default Window. So whenever a new Window is created from Caliburn, it will be MetroWindow instance.

I have a logic that creates dynamically windows through IWindowManager:

**ChatManager**

```
public class ChatManager : IChatManager
{
    private readonly IChatWindowSettings chatWindowSettings;
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;
    private readonly IChatFactory chatFactory;
    private IDictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference> chats;

    public ChatManager(IChatWindowSettings chatWindowSettings, IWindowManager windowManager, IChatFactory chatFactory)
    {
        this.chatWindowSettings = chatWindowSettings;
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        this.chatFactory = chatFactory;

        chats = new Dictionary<WeakReference, WeakReference>();
    }

    public void OpenFor(ISender sender)
    {
        var settings = chatWindowSettings.Create();
        var viewModel = CreateOrGetViewModel(sender);
        windowManager.ShowWindow(viewModel, null, settings);
    }
    private IChat CreateOrGetViewModel(ISender sender){//code...}
```

Those windows are chat windows. This works great. However, I'd like to bind/create a button directly in the MetroWindow RightCommands. This button would be bound to the IChat implementation (which is a view-model):

```
public class ChatViewModel : Screen, IChat
{
   public void DoSomething(){}
}
```

How can I accomplish such thing?

Answer (score 3):

here are some thoughts for your problem

calling sample

```
var view = new MainWindow(new ChatViewModel() { ChatName = "Chat name" });
view.Show();
```

model sample

```
public class ChatViewModel
{
    public string ChatName { get; set; }

    private ICommand chatCommand;
    public ICommand ChatCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return chatCommand
                ?? (chatCommand = new SimpleCommand() {
                    CanExecutePredicate = o => true,
                    ExecuteAction = o => MessageBox.Show("Hurray :-D")
                });
        }
    }
}
```

window code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow(ChatViewModel chatViewModel)
    {
        this.DataContext = chatViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

window xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsMetroSample.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                      Height="350"
                      Width="525">

    <Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <Controls:WindowCommands>
            <Button Content="{Binding ChatName}"
                    Command="{Binding ChatCommand}" />
        </Controls:WindowCommands>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

    <Grid>

        <!-- the content -->

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

simple command

```
public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    public Predicate<object> CanExecutePredicate { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteAction { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecutePredicate != null)
            return CanExecutePredicate(parameter);
        return true; // if there is no can execute default to true
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (ExecuteAction != null)
            ExecuteAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Didn't like this because it is not using IWindowManager, so view model project would have view reference, which I certainly would avoid.
My ChatView.xaml was a UserControl, but looking at your xaml example, I modified ChatView.xaml to inherit from MetroWindow and it works, so now I add commands and bind to ChatViewModel...

Why didn't I try this before?